# Combining Email code with if statement

Tags: powershell-2.0

I'm new to Powershell and am having trouble joining together two scripts I have.
What I want to do is check the length of all the csv files within a particular folder and if any of them are 0 Kb, I want to send off an alert email. So far I have a script which sends an email successfully and I have a script which checks the size successfully, but I am having trouble joining the two together.

Ideally it would send the name of the files which are empty in the body of the email.

The code below checks the file size and if it is greater than 1Kb it returns true.

```
    $file = 'FilePath\File1.csv'
    $Result = if (Test-Path $file) { (Get-Item $file).length -gt 1kb }

    if ($Result -eq "True") {"File1.csv Contains Data"} ELSE {"File1.csv is      Empty!"}

    $file = 'FilePath\File2.csv'
    $Result = if (Test-Path $file) { (Get-Item $file).length -gt 1kb }

    if ($Result -eq "True") {"File2.csv Contains Data"} ELSE {"File2.csv is  Empty!"}

    $file = 'FilePath\File3.csv'
    $Result = if (Test-Path $file) { (Get-Item $file).length -gt 1kb }

    if ($Result -eq "True") {"File3.csv Contains Data"} ELSE   {"File3.csv is Empty!"}

    $file = 'FilePath\File4.csv'
    $Result = if (Test-Path $file) { (Get-Item $file).length -gt 1kb }

    if ($Result -eq "True") {"File4.csv Contains Data"} ELSE {"File4.csv is Empty!"}

    $file = 'FilePath\FileName5.csv'
    $Result = if (Test-Path $file) { (Get-Item $file).length -gt 1kb }

    if ($Result -eq "True") {"File5.csv Contains Data"} ELSE {"File5.csv is Empty!"}

    $file = 'FilePath\FileName6.csv'
    $Result = if (Test-Path $file) { (Get-Item $file).length -gt 1kb }

    if ($Result -eq "True") {"File6.csv Contains Data"} ELSE {"File6.csv is Empty!"}
```

Below is the email portion

```
    $subject = "Emailtest"
    $body =  "test"
    $emailTo = "jbloggs@Madeup.com"
    $emailFrom ="JohnSmith@123.com"
    $smtpServer = “mail.madeup.com”
    $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
    $credentials=new-object system.net.networkcredential(”username”,”password”)
    $smtp.credentials=$credentials.getcredential($smtpserver,"25","basic")
    $smtp.Send($emailFrom, $emailTo, $subject, $body)
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an awful lot of (manual) work just to check for empty files. What happens when you add a seventh - do you have to edit the script?

```
$EmptyFiles = (Get-childItem -Path $FilePath -Filter *.csv | `
    where-object {$_.length -eq 0}|select-object -expandproperty Name)

$MsgBody = "The following files are empty:";
$EmptyFiles | foreach{$MsgBody+="`n$_";};

$MsgBody; # Just to output to console

$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$credentials= New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("username", $secpasswd)
$subject = "Emailtest"
$body =  "test"
$emailTo = "jbloggs@Madeup.com"
$emailFrom ="JohnSmith@123.com"
$smtpServer = “mail.madeup.com”
send-mailmessage -smtpserver $smtpServer -subject $subject -to $emailto -Credential $credentials -body $MsgBody
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Like I mentioned I am new to powershell hence the ugly code. What you've put works great and so much simpler to maintain/read. Thanks a lot.